# Permission denied when installing dlib on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, dlib

I tried to install dlib using:

```
pip install dlib
```

It appeared to be working, but then I got an error message. Here it is:

```
Collecting dlib
  Using cached dlib-19.7.0.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: dlib
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for dlib ... done
  Stored in directory: /home/andrew/.cache/pip/wheels/17/1f/5d/187f5a9fc1d63527e97fa08f5f43315e72a7b7c2ebc54e02e3
Successfully built dlib
Installing collected packages: dlib
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/andrew/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/home/andrew/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/home/andrew/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 784, in install
**kwargs
  File "/home/andrew/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 851, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
  File "/home/andrew/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1064, in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,
  File "/home/andrew/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 345, in move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "/home/andrew/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 316, in clobber
    ensure_dir(destdir)
  File "/home/andrew/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 83, in ensure_dir
    os.makedirs(path)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dlib'
```

I followed all of the previous steps, I'm just not sure why it says permission denied. Does anyone know how to fix this error?

Comment: ```sudo pip install dlib```.

Comment: Try to ask in this site: https://askubuntu.com/ it's more appropiate